# Try to add Navigation to Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-button

I'm trying to add navigation to my `WebView` but only one button works while others don't.

Here is my on click listener method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.go_btn:
            String theWebsite = URL.getText().toString();
            ourbrowser.loadUrl(theWebsite);
            break;
        case R.id.forwardbutton:
            if (ourbrowser.canGoForward()) ;
            ourbrowser.goForward();
            break;
        case R.id.rfbutton:
            ourbrowser.reload();
            break;
```

And here is my buttons XML code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/go_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/go_btn"
    android:background="#bdbdbd"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rfbutton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rfbutton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/go_rf"
    android:id="@+id/rfbutton"
    android:background="#bdbdbd"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/forwardbutton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/forwardbutton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/go_frw"
    android:id="@+id/forwardbutton"
    android:background="#bdbdbd"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rfbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />
```

So I have Go, Forward and Refresh buttons but for a reason only the Go button works.

Please help me!

Comment: Please post your buttons code (your layout XML)

Comment: I posted it below. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: One more question: Please post your onCreate in your main activity where you initialize your stuff. Also please use the EDIT link under the question's tags and add it there instead of adding it as an answer. If you get the error message of too much code, try and add some more text.

Comment: Arved: can you also post the code where you assign the event listeners to the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is add a listener to your web view so you know when the web page has finished loading. Once it has loaded, then enable back and forward buttons.

Override with webview.setWebViewClient:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    toggleURLButtons(view.canGoBack(), view.canGoForward());
}

private void toggleURLButtons(boolean canGoBack, boolean canGoForward) {
    mGoBackwardButton.setAlpha(canGoBack == true ?  1: 0.25f);
    mGoBackwardButton.setEnabled(canGoBack);

    mGoForwardButton.setAlpha(canGoForward == true ?  1: 0.25f);
    mGoForwardButton.setEnabled(canGoForward);
}
```

Then when they are clicked the buttons should work.